# Where does the idea that you cannot conceive of light until you see it come from?

Tags: atheism, reference-request, epistemology

A friend of mine is an atheist. I told him that his disbelief is an effect of his ignorance and gave him an example.

So I told him to imagine a person, who was born and lived all his life in a dark room. This person will not have an idea of the light until he or she will see it.

He enjoyed my argument and asked me to give him the book where I got this thought experiment. I think I must have read it before, because I couldn't invent it myself. Can you help me remember where I read it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please consider taking the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking out [how we are different from other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).

Comment: Shopping list questions are off topic

Comment: I think the OP was trying to say that they thought they must've read it some where, which makes this into a reference request question, not a shopping list question.

Comment: Possibly originally from Plato's *Republic* and its image of the cave? Many works in the last 2300+ years have borrowed the idea.

Answer (score 3):

C S Lewis, [apparently](http://www.ashestobeauty.net/cs-lewis-quotes/) in [*Mere Christianity*](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_8?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=mere%20christianity&sprefix=mere+chr%2Cstripbooks%2C327&rh=i%3Astripbooks%2Ck%3Amere%20christianity), does mention the concept of not knowing the concept of dark or light:

> My argument against God was that the universe seemed so cruel and unjust. But how had I got this idea of just and unjust? A man does not call a line crooked unless he has some idea of a straight line. What was I comparing this universe with when I called it unjust? If the whole show was bad and senseless from A to Z, so to speak, why did I, who was supposed to be part of the show, find myself in such a violent reaction against it?... Of course I could have given up my idea of justice by saying it was nothing but a private idea of my own. But if I did that, then my argument against God collapsed too - for the argument depended on saying the world was really unjust, not simply that it did not happen to please my fancies. Thus, in the very act of trying to prove that God did not exist - in other words, that the whole of reality was senseless - I found I was forced to assume that one part of reality - namely my idea of justice - was full of sense. If the whole universe has no meaning, we should never have found out that it has no meaning: just as, if there were no light in the universe and therefore no creatures with eyes, we should never have known it was dark. Dark would be without meaning.

[I don't have a copy, and Google Books doesn't help with an authoritative source, probably because Lewis's writings are still in copyright.]

Answer (score -1):

The concept is present in C.S. Lewis's "The Silver Chair" (towards the end, when the witch is seeking to convince the Children, Puddleglum and Prince Rilian that Narnia & Aslan are just fantasies - and it's actually not even all of life - just a long time), I wouldn't be surprised if he  also had something to that effect in "Mere Christianity".